# what is the difference between an elliptical and circular paraboloid? (3D)

Tags: geometry, graphing-functions, 3d

My textbook uses the terms interchangably, and they look the same in graphs, so I was wondering if there a difference between the two? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All circular paraboloids are elliptical paraboloids but not all elliptical paraboloids are circular paraboloids.

More precisely, an elliptical paraboloid in a surface which has parabolic cross sections in 2 orthogonal directions and 1 elliptical cross section in the other orthogonal direction.

[image]

(An elliptical paraboloid)

Because a circle is just a special type of ellipse (using one common definition of ellipse), a circular paraboloid (defined the same as elliptical paraboloid but with the last cross section being circular) is just a special type of elliptical paraboloid.

[image]
(A circular paraboloid)

If you'd prefer just to see the equations, the equation of an elliptical paraboloid is given by $$\frac zc = \left(\frac xa\right)^2 + \left(\frac yb\right)^2$$
If $a=b$, then this elliptical paraboloid is also a circular paraboloid.

Comment: Would $z=9-x^2-y^2$ be a circular paraboloid?

Comment: @Burt Yes, it will be a circular paraboloid. It will open downward (because c=-1) and start opening from (0,0,9)