# A circular paraboloid can be a elliptic paraboloid?

Tags: graphing-functions, conic-sections, quadrics

I'm aware of this similiar question:

[what is the difference between an elliptical and circular paraboloid? (3D)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1249308/what-is-the-difference-between-an-elliptical-and-circular-paraboloid-3d)

But I need help in a different way. In my calculus exam, I was asked to name the following surface:

$$(x-2)^2+(y-4)^2+1=z$$

I named it as an **elliptic paraboloid**, and according to my teacher, it is wrong because the correct answer is **circular paraboloid**.

What I was thinking at that time was that it can't be wrong to call elliptic paraboloid since horizontal planes would give a circumference which is a specific case of a ellipse.

Later I questioned why my question was wrong and explained the above. She gave me an explanation that I really couldn't understand at the time, but it was short and not convincing.

So I'm searching for definitions of a elliptic paraboloid and the "best" thing I found was this from a dictionary (not good I know, that's why I need your help, please):

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Elliptic+paraboloid

Is it going to be convincing? How can I argue in my case?

Calculus is really important to my course and I want to do good. Thanks in advance, sorry my english.

Comment: Do you not understand that your surface is a circular paraboloid, or are you questioning whether the teacher is right to accept only "circular paraboloid" (not "elliptical paraboloid") as a correct and complete answer to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A circle is a special case of an ellipse; a circular paraboloid is a special case of an elliptic paraboloid. This is how I use these terms, and so do many others.

But it's possible that your teacher used them differently, when introducing these terms *in the context of the class*. That's her decision, and it's natural that she expects answers to be consistent with the terminology adopted for the class.

Also, even when circular is considered a special case of elliptical paraboloid, there may still be an expectation that a student will pick the answer that is *the best* description of the object. The more specific description "circular" conveys more information and is to be preferred.

Answer (score 1):

$$(x-2)^2+(y-4)^2=a^2$$

is a circle with radius $a$ whose center is at $2,4$

$$(x-2)^2+(y-4)^2+1=z$$

is a circular paraboloid with whose center is at $2,4$

Instead of looking at coefficients of $x^2, y^2$ ( which must be equal for circularity ) you are looking at other displacement coefficients that are unequal.